# PHP function for adding sub-array to a multi-dim array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, append

I am having trouble finding the right function for this.

I have a session array

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][0] = (
'item_name'=>'some name',
'item_price'=>'29.99',
...
)
```

I need to append another array that has a specific key. The array is from a $_POST object.

```
$_POST['copy'] = array (
'name'=>'my name',
'office'=>'my office'
)
```

Appended session to look like this.

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][0] = (
'item_name'=>'some name',
'item_price'=>'29.99',
...
'copy'=>array(
    'name'=>'my name',
    'office'=>'my office'
    )
)
```

I tried array push but this gives me an indexed key for the appended array instead of 'copy'

I know the index of the parent array so i could create the new sub array and then loop the $_POST into it but that doesn't seem right either.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: last code block of my question...

Comment: Ah yes, you did say that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing the point - but cant you just do:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][0]['copy'] = $_POST['copy'];
```

Comment: Or even the code that is written in the question: `$_SESSION['cart_items'][0] = (
'item_name'=>'some name',
'item_price'=>'29.99',
'copy'=>array(
    'name'=>'my name',
    'office'=>'my office'
    )
)`

Comment: Ok, yeah I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'][0][$key] = $_POST[$key]; // as you said you know the key .. is it only one?
```